# Aligning buttons in my header

Tags: html, css

Currently I have 8 buttons, all displayed side by side horizontally, as part of my navigation bar.

I would like to have the first four buttons right aligned, and the last four buttons right aligned on my page.

I am fairly new to HTML5 and css.

Comment: Please share your code (html/css) or demo link. Thanx

Comment: So you want them all right aligned? Or is that a typo?

Comment: "right aligned ... right aligned", maybe right and left?

Comment: Could you create a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: put `float:left` for four button and `float:right` for next four buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick example. Just share your links in two containers and use the float property:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 960px;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: black;
}
nav .logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: white;
}
nav li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
nav ul {
  margin: .3em;
  padding: 0;
}
nav .left-menu {
  float: left;
}
nav .right-menu {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 2em;
}
nav .right-menu::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <span class="logo">LOGO</span>
  <ul class="left-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
 <ul class="right-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: BTW, if you want a dynamic height don't forget about clearfix (if you use floats) http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/, here's this example but without fixed height http://jsfiddle.net/infous/3zds0v51/1/

Answer (score 0):

`Float` is your friend. `Float: right;` will align element right in it's parent and will force other content to flow around floated element. So you have to float first four button right, and float remaining buttons right or left (if you've mistaken about direction in your original question).  Have a look at [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/float) and [demo](http://codepen.io/ThiRaBrTNK/pen/rOVxeE).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Thanks, i've completed my answer with details.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox has an option for this:

```css
.wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: .25em;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 .25em;
}
.box:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-item-align: end;
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```